# How to sum (pivot?) columns by key in first column?

Tags: r

If I have a table like this:

```
user,v1,v2,v3
a,1,0,0
a,1,0,1
b,1,0,0
b,2,0,3
c,1,1,1
```

How to I turn it into this?

```
user,v1,v2,v3
a,2,0,1
b,3,0,3
c,1,1,1
```

Comment: `aggregate(.~user, this, sum)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sum a variable by group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `base R` `aggregate` for getting the `sum` of columns by group.  Here, we use the formula method where `.` implies all other variables, while the 'user' on the RHS of `~` is the grouping variable.  We specify the `FUN=sum` to get the `sum` of all other columns.

```
aggregate(.~user, df1, sum)
```

Or we can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'user', we loop (`lapply`) through the subset of data.table (`.SD`) and get the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=user]
```

Or we use `dplyr`, grouped by 'user', we get the `sum` of all other columns within `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(user) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
```